# regex receiving pattern from function as a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a sequence of number that I don't know how many digits they have, and I want to split them.

For example, if I had the following 3 strings, I would count how many numbers before the first point, then between first and second, and assume that's the pattern for my split.

```
s1 = '0.38020.40010.32500.35050.35110.4009'
s2 = '100.3100.4100.3100.3100.3100.4'
s3 = '10.3210.3411.2312.1010.40'
```

So, what I expect would be:

```
s1 = ['0.3802', '0.4001', '0.3250', '0.3505', '0.3511', 0.4009']
s2 = ['100.3', '100.4', '100.3', '100.3', '100.3', '100.4']
s3 = ['10.32', '10.34', '11.23', '12.10', '10.40']
```

I've already tried this, but actually it's doing nothing:

```
import re
s1 = '0.38020.40010.32500.35050.35110.4009'
def count_digits(s):
    before = len(re.compile(r'^\d+(?=\.)').match(s).group())
    digits = len(re.findall(r'\.(\d+)\.', s)[0]) - before
    regex = "r'(?<=\.\d{%i})'" % digits
    return str(regex)

s1 = re.sub(count_digits(s1), '*', s1)
s1 = s1.split('*')
print(s1)
```

And I'm not even assuming that I might have a case where not all values have the same quantity of numbers before the point:

```
s2 = '100.3100.4100.3100.399.3100.4'
```

So, this logic would actually result in an error, but let's skip this case.

```
s2 = ['100.3', '100.4', '100.3', '100.', '399.3', 100.4']
```

Finally, my question is why my regex pattern does not work when comes from the function as a string? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume that all the values have the same number of digits *after* the decimal point, then you can get that number from the last value in the string, and then split the string using a regex which matches any number of digits before but only that many digits after the decimal point:

```
import re

def split_list(s):
    afterlen = len(re.search(r'\d+$', s).group(0))
    regex = r'(\d+\.\d{%d})' % afterlen
    return re.findall(regex, s)
    
s1 = '0.38020.40010.32500.35050.35110.4009'
s2 = '100.3100.4100.3100.3100.3100.4'
s3 = '10.3210.3411.2312.1010.40'
s4 = '100.3100.4100.3100.399.3100.4'

print(split_list(s1))
print(split_list(s2))
print(split_list(s3))
print(split_list(s4))
```

Output:

```
['0.3802', '0.4001', '0.3250', '0.3505', '0.3511', '0.4009']
['100.3', '100.4', '100.3', '100.3', '100.3', '100.4']
['10.32', '10.34', '11.23', '12.10', '10.40']
['100.3', '100.4', '100.3', '100.3', '99.3', '100.4']
```